# How create new record in multiple tables using newly create primary key in Child table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to Insert multiple rows in a table `TableA` where primary key is `Int` auto-generated, followed create records in `TableB` (1:1) relationship, using the primary key from TableA

`TableA`

```
IdA {PK}: int
name : nvchar
```

`TableB`

```
IdB {PK}: int
IdA {FK}: int
CreatedDate : DateTime
ExpriyDate:   DateTime
```

I want to perform above task under one script

Comment: If there's something in TableA you can match against your insert data, you can use the output clause to output inserted PK and some field which helps you join these two together into a temporary table and then continue with table B. If there's no such field in TableA, you can use a merge statement to output TableA.PK and some source field which doesn't exist in TableA and then continue with above

Comment: If you don't have triggers in table B, you might be able to insert into both tables at the same time using the merge with output, but this is for advanced use only

Comment: In my case there is no record exist in either table and will be new records in both table

Comment: do you have example script for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) together with [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause. `OUTPUT` clause in `MERGE` allows to access columns from both source and destination tables.

**Query**

`MERGE` can insert, update and delete, but we need only simple insert, so the join criteria is always false (`1=0`).

```
MERGE INTO TableA AS Dest
USING
(
    SELECT name, CreatedDate, ExpiryDate
    FROM #SomeSourceData
) AS Src
ON (1 = 0)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT
    (name)
VALUES
    (Src.name)
OUTPUT inserted.IdA, Src.CreatedDate, Src.ExpiryDate
INTO TableB(IdA, CreatedDate, ExpiryDate)
;
```

Here I assume that `TableA.IdA` is IDENTITY, so this column is not explicitly listed in the `INSERT` statement. Same for column `TableB.IdB`.

For each row in `#SomeSourceData` there will be one row inserted into `TableA` and one corresponding row inserted into `TableB`.

Comment: In above example, where `inserted` define? code doesn't recognised

Comment: so above code will allow me to insert new record for `TableA` and `TableB` same time with additional newly created `TableA` primary key in `TableB` as foreign Key?

Comment: It's not really at the same time but it can be done in a single transaction. Note that only `Merge` allows you to access both inserted and source data at the same output clause.

Comment: thanks for confirming.. also where to define inserted in the code? cannot recognise `inserted.IdA`

Comment: @K.Z, `inserted` table is defined in / by the `OUTPUT` clause. This is a table that has rows that were inserted by the previous `MERGE` statement. See the docs for the `OUTPUT` clause for details.

Comment: Yes, @K.Z, this `MERGE` statement with the `OUTPUT` clause inserts rows into both `TableA` and `TableB`.